# SocketIO can't emit to room

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Whenever I try to emit to room I get this error message on my server:

```
TypeError: Object #<Manager> has no method 'in'
    at Query.<anonymous> (/root/server.js:553:19)
    at /root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
    at /root/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

My code:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var router = express();
var server = http.createServer(router);
var io = socketio.listen(server);
io.in(room).emit("inGame",Date.now()+10000);`
```

Comment: Can you share some code instead of the error and the single line of code please?

Comment: added more info every other piece of code is irrelevant.

Comment: What is the variable "room" and where is the docs from the syntax "io.in().emit"?

Comment: the variable room is the name of a room freshly created. let me add that the code should work as I already had it running on a diffrent server it's just that when I moved the project I started getting this error. I checked the socket.io version and it seems to be the same as on the previous one. but I still get this error.

Comment: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: "io.in" is nowhere to be found in the docs. It does not exists according to me... Which would explain the error.

Comment: "And then simply use to or in (they are the same) when broadcasting or emitting" It does exist

Comment: io.to also doesn't work btw

Comment: What is the variable `socketio`? Maybe add all the code because there is a lot missing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111984/discussion-between-fastboy619-and-thomasbormans).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the problem. for any people who get this problem in the future
make sure you use the latest version of socket.io. before updating check your package.json to see if socketio is written to install a older version remove r update the version in the package.json.